# document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i have a dictionary and i want to insert it to a mongo database but i got this error:document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

my dictionary is like this
{'a': [1,2,3],'b': [4,5,6]}

Comment: can we see the code that triggers the error?